# About the double integral of the product of two sinc functions?

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

I want to use Matlab to compute a double integral like this:
$$
I=\int_{a_1}^{b_1}\int_{a_2}^{b_2}g(t_1,t_2)sinc(t_1)sinc(t_2)dt_1dt_2
$$
where $g(t_1,t_2)$ can  be geometric basket call options or other option payoff functions. Take geometric basket call options for example, 
$$
g(t_1,t_2)=(\sqrt{e^{t_1}}\sqrt{e^{t_2}}-K)^+
$$
where K is a strike price, and a constant.
Could anybody provide some numerical thoughts?
Thanks a lot.

p.s.:
I want to compute it faster since I have to compute many results. Instead of using for loops, is there any advice to use other numerical methods like discretization first then using fft or other matlab functions?

Comment: Have you tried `dblquad` or `integral2`? If yes, please provide info why you were not satisfied with them.

Comment: Yes, I've tried. The thing I'm not satisfied is the speed. I'm sorry I didn't make my words clearer. I want to compute many times, so instead of using for loops, is there any other numerical methods like discretization?

Comment: Please, provide some sample values of $a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2$. Also, do you need high precision?

Comment: Those are constants and real numbers like 0 to 5 or -1.2 to 2.3. If high precision required, is there any idea to deal with this?

Comment: Assuming $x = \max(0, x)$, you may try to split your domain into two regions with smooth integrand. For your function just remove $t_1 + t_2 < 2 \log K$ from the integration domain. If high precision is not needed, you may not need the adaptive techniques that MATLAB uses

Comment: What if high precision is required? Maybe you know what method or materials I might have a look?

Comment: Also what are the different values you need the integral for? Is it $K$ value or various $a_i, b_i$ for the same $K$, or both?